# How to delete All cells filtered witout headers using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new at using VBA and I have difficulties creating a VBA code that would delete all cells that have been filtered out without deleting the headers.

The code I have is below, but this is not working if the number of rows changes.

```
Range("A6").Select
Range(Selection, Selection. End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$AB$500").AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:="0"
Rows("221:221").Select
Range("O221").Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Answer (score 0):

One way...

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$AB$500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` method of `Range` object

but first you have to check if any cell has been filtered

here's a usage of it along with a little refactor of your code:

```
With Range("AB6", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference columns A:AB cells from row 6 (header) down to column A last not empty row
    .AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:="0" '<--| filter referenced range on its 28th column (i.e.: "AB") with "0"
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '<--| if any filtered cells other than headers then delete them (skipping headers)
    .Parent.autofltermode = False
End With
```

Comment: For some reasons there is an error at the level   .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete